# jeasy-ui runs the div twice

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery-easyui

In master.php

```
<?php
//echo "session check: ".$_SESSION['session_array'];
//exit;
session_start();  // Session Starts

if( !isset($_SESSION['session_array']) )
{
    header("Location: index.php");
    exit;
}

include("conn.php");
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>LMS</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jui/themes/gray/easyui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jui/general.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jui/themes/icon.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jui/jquery-1.6.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jui/jquery.easyui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.validate.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/date.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/core.js"></script>




</head>
<body class="easyui-layout">
    <div region="north" class="north_master" border="false" split="false" >
      <div style="float:left;">
        <img src="images/usr_logo.jpg" alt="Lead Management System" width="168" height="66" title="Lead Management System" >
      </div>
      <div style="float:right;">
        <br/><br/>

        <a id="logout" name="logout" href="logout.php?logout=1" class="easyui-linkbutton" iconCls="icon-cancel" onClick="javascript: return confirm('Are you sure you want to log out?');">Logout</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div region="south" class="south" border="false">
        <?php include('footer.php'); ?>
    </div>

    <div region="center" class="center" style="background-image:url(img/product-display.jpg);background-repeat:no-repeat;background-attachment:fixed;background-position:right bottom;  ">
        <?php

                        include('dashboard.php');

              ?>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

In dashboard.php

```
<script language="javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
alert("check");
});
</script>
<div class="content">
    <h1>Slot Dashboard</h1>

    <div>
    <a href="master.php?page=5" class="easyui-linkbutton">Add Slot</a>
    </div>    

    <table border='1' bordercolor='#B4B4B4'  cellpadding='1' cellspacing='0'  width='80%' align="center">
    <tr align="left">
    <th>Week</th>
    <th>Dates</th>
    <th>Status</th>
    <th>Date</th>
    <th>Action</th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>09/04/2011 - 09/10/2011</td>
    <td>Revised</td>
    <td>09/04/2011</td>
    <td><a href="#">View</a></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>09/11/2011 - 09/17/2011</td>
    <td>Revised</td>
    <td>09/11/2011</td>
    <td><a href="#">View</a></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>09/18/2011 - 09/24/2011</td>
    <td>Not Submitted</td>
    <td>09/18/2011</td>
    <td><a href="#">View</a></td>
    </tr>

    </table>

</div>
```

**Question:** While master.php runs "`check`" alerts twice.
I need to know why "`check`" alerts twice. How to solve this

```
<div region=center>
```

The scripts within the div runs twice. there is some bug with jeasy-ui. Help me how to solve that.

Comment: In my test alert "Included page" alerts one time. Are you sure you test this code?

Comment: I copied the code you posted above and it only alerts "Included page" 1 time. Is this your complete script ?

Comment: not possible, can you upload this somewhere and share link ?

Comment: which browser and OS? I also tried on IE windows, Firefox Linux, Opera Linux and didn't have this problem.

Comment: i had updated my question with entire codes. Help me in advance

Comment: I found the problem becoz of using jquery.easyui.min.js. script runs twice in the include page. so problem is with jquery.easyui.min.js. How to get rid of this.....

Comment: Does footer.php include dashboard.php as well? If you look at the page source in the browser, do you see the JavaScript snippet twice?

Comment: no. problem is with jquery.easyui.min.js plugin. this plugin runs the <div region="center"> codes twice.... Anybody who had used this plugin help us

Comment: I know I'm a little late to the party but FYI this is now fixed in easyui 1.3

Answer (score 1):

Technically included page alert shouldn't fire twice. it is only possible in case of you add sample.php file in php.ini as `auto_append_file`

Answer (score 0):

i found same problem in easyui every version, when script is included in to panel/layout, the script will be run twice, the reason I think:
the page be loaded in browser ,the browser run the script of page once, when dom is loaded ,the easyui render style for the node in dom, the script in the node will be called second by easyui.
this problem isn't only in layout , but in panel, Maybe even for the every thing inherit from panel.
this problem may be in the easyui's root render method, so I can't find solved for this without src.
now i have to change easyui to another ui framework.
example for theis problem, the alert be called twice in browser:

```
</div>

<div region="south" class="south" border="false">
</div>

<div region="center" class="center" >
      <script>
        alert("here");
      </script>
</div>
```